# How can there be people who believe in the concept of "free will"?

Tags: free-will

For a number of years now, I've been increasingly frustrated whenever I hear anyone talk about "free will" or "his life choices", etc. It's got to the point where I'm really, really annoyed just knowing that people seriously and fully believe in this concept, which has fundamental implications on their entire view of this reality.

Basically, anyone who believes that there is such a thing as "free will" is really saying the following:

1. Any evil person is evil just because he has made an active choice to be evil.
2. Any good person is good just because he has made an active choice to be good.
3. Anyone can choose to be either good or evil; it's just a matter of "really trying".

With this in mind, it makes perfect sense for them to sentence people to death/life in prison over any crime, because, after all, they **chose** to commit those evil acts with their **free will**. In the same convenient way, the same people can feel perfectly good about themselves, because they have actively **chosen** to be good.

***However***, there is a very serious, fundamental flaw with this concept. Why on Earth would anyone **choose** to be:

- Evil?
- Lazy?
- Stupid?
- Rude?
- Impatient?
- Envious?
- Overweight?
- Thinking sinful thoughts?
- Any negative trait you can think of?

It just fundamentally doesn't add up. ***Naturally***, nobody would ever choose any of those traits. If they did, they by definition must not have a free will, which is a very confusing paradox. A "neutral entity", given the choice to pick traits, would naturally always pick ones which give them the least amount of problems and most amount of pleasure/bliss. Anything else would not be "free will" but some sort of mental illness/confusion. Imagine an individual who "choses" to be born a pedophile in this world, for example. It just isn't going to happen; it's extremely inconvenient at the very least, and simply not desirable.

If I were given the choice to pick my own traits right now, I would completely transform my physical and mental being into a handsome, healthy, young man with an extremely attractive voice and personality, who desires only plain-looking, average females (since they are in abundance in this world), who never has any kind of problematic or evil thought in my head, and is fully, 100% well-adjusted to this world in every sense. In short, I would **choose** to be a perfect human being.

In reality, I'm fat, aging, short, ugly, have all kinds of physical and mental problems, no friends, no girlfriend or wife, nobody left whatsoever who wants anything to do with me, etc. Basically, anything bad you can think of, I am/have it. Hearing, or seeing it implied, that I somehow **chose** these traits and this existence really angers and saddens me at the same time. And that's another trait I would "choose away", by the way; I would never get angry, or frustrated, or sad, or annoyed whatsoever. I would **choose** a personality which exists in 100% perfect bliss from the moment I'm born into this planet to the second I die, never once experiencing anything unpleasant or bothersome.

Can you see where I'm going with this? There just is no logical way for there to be such a thing as "free will".

From the moment I open my eyes every day, I'm constantly bombarded with thoughts and impulses. I did not sit with a configuration file and select these thoughts and impulses. They come from within me, due to my biological programming. They **force** me to do things, and not do other things, and there is literally nothing I can do about it. Those who think otherwise tend to (unsurprisingly) be successful in life, and obviously such individuals are more likely to believe in a "free will" since that makes them feel superior (which they are, but not by choice). They can laugh at people like me and say: "Yeah, well, maybe if you stopped being a lazy bum who never had any ambition and just feels sorry for yourself all the time, and keeps blaming your failures on the supposed lack of free will, you wouldn't be such a loser today!"

It's quite possible -- even likely -- that I would be just like that if I had been born with better genes. It seems to be more or less the way it goes. Similarly, losers such as myself often **do** talk about how unfair life is and whatnot. I acknowledge this, but again, that "whining" is also not something I'm "proud" of and actively do; my body just does what my brain tells it, and my brain is not controlled by me. Thank God I didn't get even worse/scarier genes, forcing me into committing horrible murderous acts and whatnot...

I could go on about this forever, but I would be extremely interested in hearing a ***reasonable*** counter-argument. You see, I've never once in my life heard or read anything of the sort. I'm always laughed away as some kind of joker when I bring this up, even though it completely changes everything once you realize it.

I understand that all the big religions (I think) talk about there being such a thing as "free will", given by God, but let's be blunt: even a God who can do anything still is somehow bound by some sort of basic logic, even when including supernatural elements; a human being cannot exist with wildly varying genes/DNA, yet still possess "free will". In fact, even if we all had the exact same DNA, that still says nothing about there being a "free" will. We just would all have the *same* will!

It goes without saying that each person is bound by these "rules" which they were born with. This naturally includes my "free" thoughts about this very topic, and my conclusions.

Of course, the circumstances matter as well, but those are also not up to your "free will". I did not choose to be born where I was born, or by the parents who made me, nor did I get a "menu" to pick my personality details before entering this world. Nor did my parents, so I cannot blame them for having me, even though I often curse them for it.

The scary conclusion of all this is of course that you can never blame any person for anything whatsoever. No matter how hard they concentrate to either be good or evil, it's ultimately not their choice but only a result of their natural urges and ways of thinking. Even if somebody "proves me wrong" by living a perfectly good life until one day at age 45, when they just take a gun and shoot a bunch of innocent people, then claiming it was their "own free will" that did it, I would still just be able to say that they always had that in them; that's just how they are wired. It was not a free will, just as little as the victims didn't choose to be shot that day.

I genuinely hope that somebody will respond with something that really makes me rethink this whole thing, because I cannot see what that could possibly be. I have thought about this very deeply and for a very long time and the only "argument" for "free will" I have found is that it's way too scary to imagine the opposite, which I actually agree very much with. I'm freaked out of my mind after coming to this conclusion.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. This is a site for asking questions rather than venting frustrations and getting feedback. You can browse existing threads tagged "free will", and read [IEP, Free Will and Determinism](https://www.iep.utm.edu/freewill/#H3). See if you can ask something more specific than "respond with something that really makes me rethink this whole thing".

Comment: @Conifold — It *was* a nice rant, though... I'll give an answer below, just to be good-natured about it, so please don't close the question until tomorrow.

Comment: @TedWrigley I wouldn't. We do not want to encourage more of this, and there is nothing in this one not already addressed multiple times in multiple places.

Comment: @Conifold — I dislike seeing someone suffer, and I *can* give a decent philosophical response to this. I understand your point about not encouraging this kind of thing, but I hardly think that's relevant; the people who do this kind of thing aren't prone to looking for approval first, and closing this a day earlier or later isn't going to make much of a difference to unwanted traffic. Of course, I'll bow to your preferences if you really want to axe it; I'm just sayin'...

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Many people don't believe we have free will and don't find that fact scary. I'm one of them. Feel free to chat me here if you'd like to discuss it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok... First, let's clear up a confusion about the philosophical nature of this concept 'free will.' Free will suggests that we have the power to *choose otherwise* than we actually do. It doesn't mean that we do not have biological imperatives; it doesn't mean that we lack cognitive programming; it doesn't mean that we are free of social and cultural restraints, or of the circumstances of place and context we find ourselves in. It merely suggests that within that mass of limitations and habituations we have a certain amount of wiggle room; an ability to assess the cards we have been dealt and play the hand this way or that way. It may not be *easy* to make that choice; it may take time and effort to overcome our thoughtless, reactive aspects; it may not be possible to get exactly the outcomes we imagine (which may be more a problem with our imaginations than with the world), but the concept of free will implies the existence of a capacity to choose.

You're correct that no one would *naturally* choose to be evil, stupid, lazy, rude, or etc. But you fail to appreciate the flexibility of the human mind when it comes to moral value judgements. I guarantee you that:

- The people we consider evil sees themselves as virtuous
- The people we see as stupid think of themselves as righteous
- The people we see as lazy consider themselves free spirits
- The people we find rude call themselves honest and forthright

The problem isn't that these people are trying to be *bad*; the problem is that they are trying to be *good* according to lights that you and I disagree with, and likely do not understand. And that is part of free will; that is where free will is most often exercised. Changing our value structures changes how we evaluate situations, which changes the choices we make in those situations.

You talk a lot about *blame* — an external, social evaluation — but neglect to talk about the internal, personal aspect of *responsibility*. If a man commits an 'evil' act he is responsible for that action, because in the last instant he made the *choice* to follow through. He's responsible for that.  Whether he's to *blame* is a different and far more complex question that must consider far more about that man's life and mental state than is contained in the mere act. Assessing blame is sometimes necessary, but more often it's mere self-torture, with little or no value. Recognizing what we are responsible for (and we are not responsible for) is an essential component of any concept of free will; assigning blame only serves to deny free will in order to protect our egos.

Without getting needlessly Buddhist, I should point out that your thoughts are not you. They are things you have. If you feel *forced* or *bombarded* by your thoughts, urges, emotions, and whatnot, it's only because you have not seen the space between yourself and your thoughts. Watch yourself being *forced*; see yourself being *bombarded*. You'll realize that neither is actually happening, that you're merely allowing yourself to be swept away because you haven't yet learned to detach. That's a skill you can develop, and in doing so you develop your sense of free will.

I'm sorry you're suffering this much, but denying your own capacity to escape suffering won't help relieve your suffering. From my perspective — and this is the morbid irony I always feel in these discussions — you are choosing to believe you cannot choose, because that paradoxical absolves guilt, shame, frustration, perhaps even rage at your life condition. And really, we've all been there, we've all done that, in one way or another and to a greater or lesser extent. But it's a poisonous mindset. It gives license to the worst parts of our nature (the ones we always associate with thoughtless reactivity). Better to assume we have free will and be compassionate about our failures to achieve it fully, than to assume we don't and wallow in unconscious misery.

Comment: The other problem OP has is identifying "free will" with control over the outcomes of choices. It is a bit ironic that acting "freely" is acting most predictably, for "the least amount of problems and most amount of pleasure/bliss", and "anything else would not be "free will"". But I think you are right, the OP is not really looking for counterarguments, but rather consolation and support.

Comment: "Free will suggests that we have the power to choose otherwise than we actually do." This can't stand as a definition of free will without qualification. It's the main Incompatibilist theory of free will, but compatibilists will disagree, and even incompatibilists may disagree that it's a sufficient condition for free wil becuase if i make a decision D at time t, but quantum randomness could have caused me to make decision E instead, that randomness doesn't grant free will. Otherwise i think this answer does a good job of clearing up some misconceptions the OP has

Comment: @DanielPrendergast — Sure, I guess, but compatibilism is silly. Sorry to be blunt.  At any rate, I'm not trying to answer the question of whether free will exists. I'm suggesting three things: (1) if FW exists, this is what it means. (2) if FW doesn't exist, all bets are off. (3) We have to act as though #1 is true, because (a) if #2 is true it doesn't matter how we act, but (b) if #1 is true, it *does* matter how we act. A person without free will is inconsequential; a person with free will who pretends not to have it is a monster. Neither is a savory outcome, so we're left with the other.

Comment: @Conifold — Yeah, I know. People tend to envision *free will* as power, and they immediately yoke it to all of their cravings and desires and impulses. But really, *free will* is the power to **escape** that yoke, and that is incredibly hard for most people to see. And yes, I think you're right about the consolation and support... But we all need that sometimes, and I'm glad to give it when I can.

Comment: Your definition of free will is merely that: yours. The term "free will" is used differently within philosophy (and in common parlance, and in legal contexts, and religions) I don't think it's useful to tell what free will "really" is, because it depends on who you ask. I have other issues with your answer but would need to take it to a chat room.

Comment: @Chelonian — An appeal to relativism is not an argument; it's a whine. I've given the definition of free will that is typically used in philosophical discussions, and if you dislike it you are free to write your *own* answer with your *own* definition (presuming you can defend it analytically). If you'd like to discuss this further in chat, that's alright with me, but let's keep personalizations out of it, and reach for proper universalism.

Comment: As you prefer, but that's your choice, not mine. I respect good reasoning, I am dismissive of bad reasoning, and I know the difference. Don't take it personally; take it as a challenge.